# Swift 4.2 - UIColor.lightGray results in the color black

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I updated a codebase from Swift 3.2 to Swift 4.2

All of the sudden, any UI element that is assigned the color `UIColor.lightGray` produces a black result at runtime:

`self.emptyTableView.messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray`

Any idea what's causing this?

Thank you for any insights

Edit:

Here are the extensions for UIColor I found:

```
extension UIColor {
func colorWithRedValue(_ redValue: CGFloat, greenValue: CGFloat, blueValue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: redValue/255.0, green: greenValue/255.0, blue: blueValue/255.0, alpha: alpha)
}

func facebookBlue() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.35, blue:0.60, alpha:1.0)
}

func twitterBlue() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.60, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
}

func goOutGreen() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.56, green:0.78, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
}

func goOutTransparent() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
}

func goOutClearGreen() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.91, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)
}

func transparentBlack() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.6)
}

func darkShade() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
}

func greenNormal() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.83, blue:0.15, alpha:1.0)
}

func goOutRed() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.77, green:0.05, blue:0.05, alpha:1.0)
}

func goOutBlue() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.56, blue:0.89, alpha:1.0)
}

func goOutGray() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.29, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
}

func adminBlack() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.09, blue:0.12, alpha:1.0)
}

func adminGray() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.902, green:0.902, blue:0.902, alpha:1)
}

func adminBackground() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.95, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0)
}

func adminPurple() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.36, green:0.33, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)
}

func adminDarkPurple() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.265, green:0.24, blue:0.301, alpha:1)
}

func adminLightPurple() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.47, blue:0.47, alpha:1.0)
}

func eventDraft() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.21, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
}

func eventPending() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.54, blue:0.90, alpha:1.0)
}

convenience init(hexString: String) {
    var cString: String = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString = (cString as NSString).substring(from: 1)
    }

    if (cString.characters.count != 6) {
        self.init(white: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
    } else {
        let rString: String = (cString as NSString).substring(to: 2)
        let gString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 2) as NSString).substring(to: 2)
        let bString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 4) as NSString).substring(to: 2)

        var r: CUnsignedInt = 0, g: CUnsignedInt = 0, b: CUnsignedInt = 0;
        Scanner(string: rString).scanHexInt32(&r)
        Scanner(string: gString).scanHexInt32(&g)
        Scanner(string: bString).scanHexInt32(&b)

        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / CGFloat(255.0), green: CGFloat(g) / CGFloat(255.0), blue: CGFloat(b) / CGFloat(255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1))
    }
}
}
```

and this one:

```
import Foundation

internal extension UIColor {

/// Hexadecimal representation of the UIColor.
/// For example, UIColor.blackColor() becomes "#000000".
var hex: String {
    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0
    self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: nil)

    let r = Int(255.0 * red)
    let g = Int(255.0 * green)
    let b = Int(255.0 * blue)

    let str = String(format: "#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b)
    return str
}

 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't be any bugs with this. Make sure you're not setting the color elsewhere. Might be helpful if you would show the entire view controller.

Comment: @Starsky I just added some UIColor extensions I found in the code base.  Thank you!

Comment: These extensions are irrelevant. There's no lightGray color overriden or something like that. It means you're using the default lightGray. Please show the cellForRowAt datasource func, willDisplayCell (if you've implemented), and if you're using custom tableView cell, show it's code as well. Might be needed to see your label in storyboard and what options have you set for it. Optionally, you could show the print screen with the result you're getting.

Comment: By Default "Highlighted" part of UILabel in Attributes Inspector is black color. wondering just in case your label is highlighted?